# How to reload the time zone tables to stay current with time zone changes in Aurora MySQL version 3?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, timezone, amazon-aurora, timezone-offset

Mexico didn't resume the usage of Daylight Saving Time (DST) as planned in April 2023; instead the country will be on Standard time all year long.

Currently I'm using named time zones in queries defined in a Business intelligence tool ([Metabase](https://www.metabase.com/)) connected to Aurora MySQL (version 3) and I'm unable to update the time zone tables in the `mysql` database to get the local timestamps correctly.

Data:

| id | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-15 22:59:55.211225 |

Example query:

```
select
    id,
    convert_tz(created_at, "UTC", "America/Mexico_City") as local_created_at
from items;
```

Output (computed using out of date zone offset `-05:00`, in DST):

| id | local_created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-15 17:59:55.211225 |

Expected output (using zone offset `-06:00`, in Standard time):

| id | local_created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-15 14:59:55.211225 |

As a first step I applied any pending maintenance, Aurora engine was upgraded to version 3.03.1 and underlying operating system was also updated. Then, I followed the instructions described in the MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual ([Populating the Time Zone Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation)) and summarized below:

Pass the zoneinfo directory path name to [mysql_tzinfo_to_sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) and send the output into the mysql program.

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -h <db-host> -u <master-user> -p mysql
```

The above command uses the zoneinfo database (the set of files describing time zones) and generates the sql statements that are passed to the mysql program as input.

After I executed the command, I got the following error:

> ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'user1'@'%' to database 'mysql'

then I read about the [Aurora MySQL privilege-mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.AuroraMySQL.Compare-80-v3.html#AuroraMySQL.privilege-model), which poses the following:

> With Aurora MySQL version 3, you can't modify the tables in the `mysql` database directly. In particular, you can't set up users by inserting into the `mysql.user` table. Instead, you use SQL statements to grant role-based privileges. You also can't create other kinds of objects such as stored procedures in the `mysql` database. You can still query the `mysql` tables.

Note: `user1` is the master user account and I verified that the user has the role `rds_superuser_role`

Comment: Not an aurora page, but: "Every time RDS releases a new minor maintenance release of MySQL, it ships with the latest time zone data at the time of the release" - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Concepts.LocalTimeZone.html   have you updated to the latest available update?

Comment: If true, the mexico changes from tzdata 2022g should be in Aurora MySQL 3.02.3 or above

Comment: @ysth Yes, I have updated to the latest available version (3.03.1)

Comment: And that didn't have the mexico update?

Comment: No, it didn't have it